# When exporting a networkx graph to GML, how can I explicitly set the labels?

Tags: networkx

When exporting a networkx graph to GML, how can I explicitly set the labels? Given this script:

```
import networkx as nx

G2 = nx.DiGraph()
G2.add_node( "id:UserA", label="Cat" )
G2.add_node( "id:Userb", label="Dog" )
nx.write_gml(G2, 'tt.gml')
```

I get

```
graph [
  directed 1
  node [
    id 0
    label "id:UserA"
  ]
  node [
    id 1
    label "id:Userb"
  ]
]
```

where I want

```
graph [
  directed 1
  node [
    id 0
    label "Cat"
  ]
  node [
    id 1
    label "Dog"
  ]
]
```

I can explicitly color nodes by adding `graphics={'fill': '#FF0000'}` but adding `label` this way does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `LabelGraphics` attribute. This works with yEd editor at least.

```
import networkx as nx

G2 = nx.DiGraph()
G2.add_node( "id:UserA", LabelGraphics={"text" : "Cat"} )
G2.add_node( "id:Userb", LabelGraphics={"text" : "Dog"} )
nx.write_gml(G2, 'tt.gml')
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that as mentioned in the [docs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.gml.write_gml.html):

> Graph attributes named 'directed', 'multigraph', 'node' or 'edge',node attributes named 'id' or **'label'**, edge attributes named 'source' or 'target' (or 'key' if G is a multigraph) **are ignored** because these attribute names are used to encode the graph structure.

---

i.e if you set the attribute name to `label` it will be ignored since it is a name which is *always* used to define the graph structure, that is why the `label` that you see does not show as the value you've set it to. So what you can do is to simply set these attributes with another name, such as:

```
G2 = nx.DiGraph()
G2.add_node( "id:UserA", tag="Cat" )
G2.add_node( "id:Userb", tag="Dog" )
nx.write_gml(G2, 'tt.gml')
```

In this case you'd get:

```
graph [
  directed 1
  node [
    id 0
    label "id:UserA"
    tag "Cat"
  ]
  node [
    id 1
    label "id:Userb"
    tag "Dog"
  ]
]
```

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer, but this means that what I want is simply not possible. GML-capable viewers/editors will use the "label" field to display alongside the node (https://socnetv.org/docs/formats.html#GML), so putting it in another field won't do the job.